# Create columns based on rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and I am looking for a nice way to transform this dataframe:

| Date | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2022 | A | 0 |
| 01-01-2022 | B | 1 |
| 01-01-2022 | C | 1 |
| 02-01-2022 | A | 1 |
| 02-01-2022 | B | 1 |
| 02-01-2022 | C | 0 |

To this dataframe:

| Name | Value_before | Value_after |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| C | 1 | 0 |

First table contains only data from two dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming:

- that you have only 2 dates
- that there are no duplicated Name per date

You can use a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) taking advantage of the fact the `pivot` sorts the columns, then [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) to use your custom names

```
out = (df
   .assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']))  # ensure datetime for correct sorting
   .pivot('Name', 'Date', 'Value')
   .set_axis(['Value_before', 'Value_after'], axis=1)
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
  Name  Value_before  Value_after
0    A             0            1
1    B             1            1
2    C             1            0
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for are [pivot tables](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date": [date(2022,1,1), date(2022,1,1), date(2022,1,1), date(2022,1,2), date(2022,1,2), date(2022,1,2)],
    "Name": ["A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"],
    "Value": [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
})

print(pd.pivot_table(df, values="Value", index="Name", columns="Date"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    dd1=dd.loc[:,'Value']
    dd1.index=['Value_before','Value_after']
    return dd1
df1.groupby("Name").apply(function1)

Value  Value_before  Value_after
Name                            
A                 0            1
B                 1            1
C                 1            0
```